# Back button event is not fired after soft keyboard hide event

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an application, where there is a log-in page and I have included

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", handleBackButton, false);
   function handleBackButton() {
}
```

to handle back button event which works perfectly fine, but when I click on any input field softkeyboard is shown up and on pressing the back back button the key board gets down but when I click again on the back button the app crashes instead of calling the "handle backbutton" function

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.handleBackButton();
}
```